# $\sigma$-finite measures and a sequence of simple measurable functions.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose that $f$ is a non-negative, measurable function and that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. Show that there exists a sequence $(\phi_{n})$ of simple measurable functions that monotonically increase to $f$ such that $\mu (\{x \in X: \phi_{n}(x) \neq 0 \}) < \infty  $ for each $n$.

The previous chapter introduced the theorem that proves the existence of such a sequence of simple functions for a non-negative measurable function. I tried toying around with that sequence for awhile and using the fact that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finte, but I cannot seem to pin this problem down. A hint would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can assume that there exists $\phi_n$  monotonically increasing to $f$. Since $(X, \mathcal{M},\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite, you can consider $\{X_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ measureable so that $\cup_iX_i =X$ and $\mu(X_i)< \infty$ for each $X_i$.

Now consider $Y_i = \cup_{i=1}^n X_i$. (I'll let you deduce a convenient property of these $Y_i$'s.) Let $\chi_i$ be the indicator function of $Y_i$. That is, $\chi_i(x)=1$ if $x\in Y_i$ and $\chi_i(x)=0$ otherwise. Note that $\chi_i$ is measureable. Think about how to "combine" these indicators $\{\chi_n\}$ with $\{\phi_n\}$ to get a sequence with the desired property.

Comment: Is it $\phi_n \chi_n$?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're proved this for a *finite* measure $\mu$?

Sigma-finiteness means that there is some countable collection of open sets each of finite measure, whose union is the whole space. You can use the finite-case construction on each of these open sets. Then simply join these constructions together, one by one.

Comment: I don't think $\mu$ needs to be finite for this to work.

Comment: I slightly misunderstood the wording of the question!