# Show there exist simple functions $s_n$ increasing to $f$ at each point such that $\mu(\left\lbrace x:s_n(x)\neq 0\right\rbrace)<\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, simple-functions

I am aware that this is a duplicate questions, but none of the answers on here were able to help me.  Here is the problem.

Suppose $f$ is non-negative and measurable and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.  Show there exist simple functions $s_n$ increasing to $f$ at each point such that $\mu(\left\lbrace x:s_n(x)\neq 0\right\rbrace)<\infty$ for each $n$.

I basically know two things from previous work in this class.

1) There exists a sequence of non-negative simple functions $s_n$ increasing to $f$, and

2) There exist $E_i\in\mathcal{A}$ for $i=1,2,\dots$, such that $\mu(E_i)<\infty$ for each $i$ and $X=\cup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$.

It seems to me that these two facts should be enough to get me the proof, but I am stuck and don't know how to proceed.  I wanted to define the simple functions somehow in terms of the sets $E_i$ and see where I could go with that.  But I really need a strong hint (easy hints aren't doing it for me this semester.  This measure theory stuff is ridiculous).

Comment: If you multiply a simple function with a characteristic function of a measurable set …

Comment: ...then it will either be 0 or itself.  This means that...

Comment: Do you mean that pointwise? For each $x$, the product is $0$ or $s(x)$?

Comment: well, I guess it would be for all $x$ in the measurable set?

Comment: For all $x$ in the whole space it will be one of the two.

Comment: So if I defined $t_n=s_n\mathcal{X}_{En_i}$ we would have $\mu(t_n)=\mu(0)=0$ or $\mu(t_n)=\mu(s_n)$.  But I have no way to determine if $\mu(s_n)<\infty$.  Or if I am misunderstanding, please correct me.

Comment: You assume the $E_k$ are increasing, $E_k \subset E_{k+1}$, I suppose? [It's nowhere explicitly stated, but if they aren't, you need to modify the construction a bit.] What do you know about the set $\{ x : t_n(x) \neq 0\}$?

Comment: This is the set of $x$ for which both $s(x)\neq0$ and $\mathcal{X}_{E_i}\neq 0$.  I suppose I should be concluding the measure is finite but I just don't see it.

Comment: What do you know about the set where $\mathcal{X}_{E_i}$ is $\neq 0$?

Comment: That set has finite measure.

Comment: True. Why? And how does that help us?

Comment: It has finite measure because $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.  Why this helps, I don't know.  I know that you can write simple functions in alternate ways, so I thought maybe we could define each $s_n$ piecewise over the $E_is$, but I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: I guess the real truth is that I don't know how multiplying functions affects the measure of them.

Comment: It has finite measure because that set is $E_i$. So, what do we know about the set $\{ x : t_n(x) = s_n(x)\cdot \mathcal{X}_{E_n}(x) \neq 0\}$?

Comment: This is my problem.  I do not know what happens with measures when sets are multiplied.

Comment: We don't multiply sets. We multiply functions. And for the moment, forget about the measure, we'll deal with that later. What can you say about that set?

Comment: it is equal to $\left\lbrace x:s_n(x)\neq 0\right\rbrace$?

Comment: In general, it is a proper subset of that.

Comment: Right, in case that $\mathcal{X}=0$ but $s_n\neq 0$.

Comment: Okay, well I guess I can say that $t_n$ is itself a simple function.

Comment: Yes, the $t_n$ are simple functions. And they are increasing (non-strictly), and $\mu(\{ x : t_n(x) \neq 0\}) < +\infty$. But do you see _why_ these things are true?

Comment: $t_n$ is a simple function by the definition of simple function.  I suppose they are increasing because the $E_i$ are nested, although I never really got why we were assuming that.  As for the measure being finite, I feel that it is true but cannot explain why.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is Exercise 6.4 from "Real Analysis for Graduate Students" by Richard F Bass, so that people searching for that can have their search engine pick up this thread. Other thread with same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874187/sigma-finite-measures-and-a-sequence-of-simple-measurable-functions